# What is the most efficient way to truncate a number for a specific accuracy?

Tags: c#, math, int

What is the most efficient way to truncate a number for a specific accuracy?

Comment: From the other answers, it seems like there is some ESP going on here. I'm not psychic, can you please elaborate.

Comment: @leppie: From revision 1: `I want to get the only 3 digits of the milliseconds of System.DateTime.`

Answer (score 3):

In a `DateTime`, [Milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx) are always comprised between 0 and 999 so you don't have anything to do.

Comment: Quoting the MSDN link I posted in my answer "The milliseconds component, expressed as a value between 0 and 999." Seems logical you can't have 32 days in a month nor more than 999ms in a second.

Answer (score 1):

```
int ms = Convert.ToInt32(
             Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Substring(0, 3));
```

or

```
double Length = Math.Pow(10, (DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString().Length - 3));

double Truncate = Math.Truncate((double)DateTime.Now.Millisecond / Length);
```

---

EDIT:

After running both the below on the code I will post, the double method works well due to reuse of variables. Over an iteration of 5,000,000 DateTime.Now's (in which many will be skipped by both checks), the `SubString()` method took 9598ms, and the `Double` method took 6754ms.

EDIT#2: Edited in * 1000 into tests to make sure the iterations are running.

Code used to test as follows:

```
        Stopwatch stop = new Stopwatch();
        stop.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            int MSNow = DateTime.Now.Millisecond * 1000;

            if (MSNow.ToString().Length > 2)
            {
                int ms = Convert.ToInt32(
                    Convert.ToString(MSNow).Substring(0, 3));
            }
        }

        stop.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stop.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        stop = new Stopwatch();
        stop.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            int MSNow = DateTime.Now.Millisecond * 1000;
            int lengthMS = MSNow.ToString().Length;

            if (lengthMS > 2)
            {
                double Length = Math.Pow(10, (lengthMS - 3));
                double Truncate = Math.Truncate((double)MSNow / Length);
            }
        }

        stop.Stop();

        Console.Write(stop.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is the most *efficient* way?

Comment: @stacker - Take both, and run them through a `Stopwatch` and see which is faster?

Comment: I would say the `Math.Pow` one is much slower, but it's just a guess, test it out with a `StopWatch`.

Comment: @IVlad, Im guessing so too, with the `double` calculations. Im doing the calculation now to see.

Comment: @Stacker - There's some data for you.

Comment: @stacker - not necessarily. In the beginning tests without reuse of parameters, the string method was substantially faster. It all comes down to how you code it in the end.

Comment: this is really simple math problem. I think there is more simple solution.

Comment: @stacker - The solution is pretty simple. You take 10 to the power of the Length of the number, minus the precision, Divide the number by the power and truncate it: `Trunc(Number / (10^Number.Length - Precision))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.Floor(num * Math.Pow(10, x) + 0.5) / Math.Pow(10, x)
```

Where x your precision

Comment: Well I think i have given answer out of context. however i thought you are asking for Rounding, Anyway i can't get what does truncate even means in numbers, Anyway sorry for not picking up the context.